# How do you handle SNMP v3 Traps in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, snmp

I currently have a script that listens for incoming traffic for e-mail / syslog / and SNMP v1, I'm looking to add functionality for SNMP v3 but the ruby SNMP library doesn't include v3 support.

I prefer it to be a ruby only solution because this tool will be used by others and I don't want to require them to install something like net-snmp if I can avoid it.

Comment: sounds like it's time to shave a yak

Comment: I was hoping someone else shaved a yak and took a picture for me :p  Does anyone have some input on handling the base snmpv3 packet?  A good library in a different language that is well written I can learn from?

Comment: Yeah this doesn't look good, I don't see anything on rubyforge, github or rubygems... Looks like it is yak shaving time. There is one gem that might be useful for you, packetfu - http://code.google.com/p/packetfu/. Might make it easier to whip something together for your purposes.

Answer (score 1):

You've got a nice open source product called NET-SNMP (ex UCD-SNMP). This product is compiled for Linux-like and Windows. Inside this product you've got a daemon (service) called snmptrapd. snmptrapd is able to receive any SNMP trap (v1, v2c, V3). Around that, you will find SNMP Trap Translator. It's used to 'translate' traps received from the NET-SNMP / UCD-SNMP snmptrapd trap daemon into easy to understand messages. This tool is writen in PERL.

Another information, V3 traps and informs (aknowledged traps) are exacly the same as V2 traps and informs.

I hope it helps.

JP